# Getting column metadata from jdbc/postgresql for newly created table

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to get the column list from newly created table(it is created in the java code).
The thing is that I do not get the columns. 
The code works for tables that are already in the database, but if i create a new one and try to get the column info immediately it does not find any...

Update:
Here is full code that I used for testing:

```
@Test
public void testtest() throws Exception {
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        String tableName = "Table_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
            statement.executeUpdate(String.format("create table %s (id int primary key,name varchar(30));", tableName));
        }
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
        try (ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null)) {
            int colsFound = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                colsFound++;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Found %s cols.", colsFound));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Autocommit is set to %s.", conn.getAutoCommit()));
    }
}
```

The and the output:

```
Found 0 cols.
Autocommit is set to true.
```

Comment: do you close connection after creating new table?

Comment: Yes, I close both: the statement and the connection. Although I'm using the DriverManagerDataSource for getting the connection so it may be that it is not closed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the case of your tablename:

```
String tableName = "Table_"
```

As that is an unquoted identifier (a good thing) the name is converted to lowercase when Postgres stores its name in the system catalog.

The DatabaseMetaData API calls are case sensitive ( `"Table_"` != `"table_"`), so you need to pass the lowercase tablename:

```
ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName.toLowerCase(), null))
```

More details on how identifiers are using are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: That was the thing. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have made simple test and it seems to work. I can create new table and show its columns using PostgreSQL JDBC (I use Jython):

```
conn = db.createStatement()
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE new_table (id SERIAL, txt VARCHAR(200))")
db_meta_data = db.getMetaData()
for tbl_name in ('date_test', 'new_table'):
    print('\n-- %s --' % (tbl_name))
    rs = db_meta_data.getColumns(None, None, tbl_name, None)
    while (rs.next()):
        print('%s:%s' % (rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4)))
conn.close()
```

This code shows columns for both already existing table: `date_test` and for just created `new_table`. I also added some code to close connection after `CREATE TABLE` but my results are always the same and correct.

Maybe it is problem with your JDBC driver. I use driver from `postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar`.

It may be also problem with user permissions. Do you use the same user for both creating table and getting metadata? Is new table visible in `psql`, `pgAdmin` or other tool?

Other reason is that PostgreSQL uses transactions also for schema changes. So if you disabled default autocommit and closed connection your schema changes will be lost. Do you use `db.setAutoCommit(false)`?

You can also query PostgreSQL schema directly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_name = 'new_table'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I've updated the jdbc driver to the one that you have mentioned but it did not help. I'm using the same credentials for bot creating table and getting te column information.

Comment: So the only idea is that you create table in transaction that is not committed.

Comment: Do you see this table in `psql`?

Comment: I updated my answer with PostgreSQL schema query. Can you add it to your test code instead of querying metadata and show us result?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely giving passing table name in lower case to getColumns method does work...thanks for the query Michał Niklas it got me on the right track.

Comment: Ohhh, once I also had this problem :-)  Now I care to use only lowercase in table or column names.